# Scala: How can I split up a dataframe by row number?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to split up a dataframe of 2,7 million rows into small dataframes of 100000 rows, so end up with like 27 dataframes, which I want to store as csv files too.

I took a look at this partitionBy and groupBy already, but I don't need to worry about any conditions, except that they have to be ordered by date. I am trying to write my own code to make this work, but if you know about some Scala (Spark) functions I could use, that would be great!

Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: There are a couple of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135610/spark-scala-split-dataframe-into-equal-number-of-rows) that could get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I started with this yes, before I asked the questions, but those solutions were not really helpful to me :)

Comment: @Eva, if your goal is to break data to save smaller csv files, you can just do df.repartition(27).write.csv("/path"). You will have part000, part002, .. part026 files under "/path" folder

Comment: I will give this a try too, it seems a very simple way to do it, if it takes care of the ordering, then it should be enough too! The problem comes only when the dataframe grows, then the repartition has to be changed everytime... But for quick results it looks good! Thanks :)

Comment: Repartitioning can be costly (it moves around all your data) and will not preserve the order.

Comment: Can you add examples of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zipWithIndex` from the RDD API (no equivalent in SparkSQL unfortunately) that maps each row to an index, ranging between `0` and `rdd.count - 1`.

So if you have a dataframe that I assumed to be sorted accordingly, you would need to go back and forth between the two APIs as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// creating mock data
val df = spark.range(100).withColumn("test", 'id % 10)

// zipping the data
val partitionSize = 5 // I use 5 but you can use 100000 in your case
val zipped_rdd = df.rdd
    .zipWithIndex.map{ case (row, id) => 
        Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id / partitionSize ) 
    }

//back to df
val newField = StructField("partition", LongType, false)
val zipped_df = spark
    .createDataFrame(zipped_rdd, df.schema.add(newField))
```

Let's have a look at the data, we have a new column called partition and that corresponds to the way you want to split your data.

```
zipped_df.show(15) // 5 rows by partition
+---+----+---------+
| id|test|partition|
+---+----+---------+
|  0|   0|        0|
|  1|   1|        0|
|  2|   2|        0|
|  3|   3|        0|
|  4|   4|        0|
|  5|   5|        1|
|  6|   6|        1|
|  7|   7|        1|
|  8|   8|        1|
|  9|   9|        1|
| 10|   0|        2|
| 11|   1|        2|
| 12|   2|        2|
| 13|   3|        2|
| 14|   4|        2|
+---+----+---------+

// using partitionBy to write the data
zipped_df.write
    .partitionBy("partition")
    .csv(".../testPart.csv")
```

Comment: I try to test it in Databricks, but at this point which exact library do I have to import?
`val zipped_df = spark
    .createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema.add(newField))` for the rdd?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with databricks. Is the SparkSession created for you? If it is, I think you only need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.types._` to be able to create the `StructField` and `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. Let me update my answer :)

Comment: These imports are not resolving the issue of the createDataFrame(rdd...) part: _error: not found: value rdd_

Comment: Ho right, it's just a problem of variable name. I changed the name of one, but not of the other. Sorry. I fix the answer right away.

Comment: And yes, the SparkSession is created!

Comment: Oh I thought it is like specifying the way of creating :D thank you!