# How to split a spark scala dataframe if number of rows are greater than threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to load a huge dataframe in to parts if the number of rows are greater than threshold.
We have a threshold of 3 mil rows if the data frame has let's say 4 mil rows we want to load 3 mil rows first then load 1 mil in next loop.
I am trying following approach : this is a pseudo code what I tried but these things are not working in scala I am looking for substitute in scala ot may be a better way of doing this

```
if(deltaExtractCount > 3000000)
{
  length = len(df)
  count = 0
  while (count < length)
  { 
    new_df = df[count : count + 3000000]
    insert(new_df)
    count = count + 3M
  }
}
```

This is what I was trying but not successful. Haven't found equivalent scala function this pseudo code is more suitable for python .
I am using spark 3.1.2
and scala 2.12
Let me know how I can achieve this split if there is other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this piece of code, I hope you can understand that. I also wrote some comments to make it easier. Assume `csv` is your dataset:

```
    // Assign an increasing ID to the column, so we know which rows to get
    csv = csv.withColumn("ID", expr("row_number() over (order by name)"));

    // Total dataset count
    long count = csv.count();
    // Threshold, modify this to the number you want
    long loadThreshold = 300000;
    // This will tell you how many 'loops' you will get
    double loopingTimes = Math.ceil(count * 1.0 / loadThreshold);

    // emptyDataset is an empty dataset, I did this just to fetch the schema
    Dataset<Row> emptyDataset = csv.limit(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < loopingTimes; i++) {
        // This is the new fetched dataset
        Dataset<Row> withThreshold = csv
                .where(col("ID").gt(i * loadThreshold).and(col("ID").leq((i + 1) * loadThreshold)));

        // Once 300000 rows are fetched, union to the main file
        emptyDataset = emptyDataset.union(withThreshold);
    }
```

I did a test case with `loadThreshold` equal to 25 and a dataset `count` of 60 rows, I got `loadThreshold` = 3. Then the partitions were *fetched* this way:

1st loop: 25 rows

2nd loop: 25 rows

3rd loop: 10 rows

This is written in Java, but it is almost identical in Scala as well, good luck!

Comment: Thank you here is what I came up with and it worked its similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it its similar took hints from
[Spark Scala Split dataframe into equal number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135610/spark-scala-split-dataframe-into-equal-number-of-rows)

```
if (deltaExtractCount > 25) {

val k = 25
val totalCount = deltaExtractCount
var lowLimit = 0
var highLimit = lowLimit + k

while (lowLimit < totalCount) {
var split_df = masterLoadDf.where(s"row_num <= ${highLimit} and row_num > ${lowLimit}")
lowLimit = lowLimit + k
highLimit = highLimit + k

InsertIntoDB(split_df)


}

} else {
 InsertIntoDB(loadDeltaBatchDF)
}
```