# How to get few rows from Spark data frame on basis of some condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Data Frame like below with three column

```
id|visit_class|in_date 
+--+-----------+--------
|1|Non Hf     |24-SEP-2017
|1|Non Hf     |23-SEP-2017
|1|Hf         |27-SEP-2017
|1|Non Hf     |28-SEP-2017
|2|Non Hf     |24-SEP-2017
|2|Hf         |25-SEP-2017
```

I want to group this data frame on id then sort this grouped data on indate column and want only those rows which are coming after first occurrence of HF. The output will be like below. Means first 2 rows will drop for id =1 and first 1 row will drop for id = 2.

```
id|visit_class|in_date 
+--+-----------+--------
|1|Hf         |27-SEP-2017
|1|Non Hf     |28-SEP-2017
|2|Hf         |25-SEP-2017
```

How I will achieve this in Spark and Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Steps*:

1) Create the WindowSpec, order by `date` and partition by `id`:

2) Create a cumulative sum as indicates of whether `Hf` has appeared, and then filter based on the condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(to_date($"in_date", "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
(df.withColumn("rn", sum(when($"visit_class" === "Hf", 1).otherwise(0)).over(w))
   .filter($"rn" >= 1).drop("rn").show)

+---+-----------+-----------+
| id|visit_class|    in_date|
+---+-----------+-----------+    
|  1|         Hf|27-SEP-2017|
|  1|     Non Hf|28-SEP-2017|
|  2|         Hf|25-SEP-2017|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

<sub>Using spark 2.2.0, `to_date` with the format signature is a new function in 2.2.0</sub>

---

If you are using spark < 2.2.0, you can use `unix_timestamp` in place of `to_date`:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"in_date", "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: after applying the above logic I am getting the below error

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'sum'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;

Can you please also help me here ??

Comment: Maybe you are using spark 1.x, in which case you need `HiveContext` for the [window functions `sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319126/spark-window-functions-requires-hivecontext).

Comment: Can we do this without window function ? 
Because I am able to run this in Spark-shell but when I am creating jar in eclipse it is showing table not found error